# Change ListBoxItem.Foreground color using a Trigger

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have this listbox style but for some reason I am unable to change the foreground color based on a trigger. I would like to change the foreground color to black when the item in the listbox is selected. I searched all over and all the solutions don't seem to work in my case. Here is my list box...

```
<ListBox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectedValuePath="RecordId" ItemsSource="{Binding People}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedPersonId}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="20,5,10,5" Width="Auto" Grid.Row="1" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" x:Name="lstCustomers">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Height="Auto" Width="Auto" d:DesignWidth="545.375" d:DesignHeight="50.294">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="132.375"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Label FontSize="16" Content="{Binding FullName}" Foreground="White"/>
                    <Label FontSize="16" Content="{Binding DisplayName}" Margin="5,0,0,0" Foreground="White"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Grid.Column="1">
                    <Label Content="{Binding Date}" ContentStringFormat="yyyy/MM/dd" FontSize="24" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="White" DockPanel.Dock="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </DockPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Border BorderBrush="#26FFFFFF" BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="5" Name="Border" Margin="0,0,2,3" Padding="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#7FFFFFFF" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#0FFFFFFF"></Setter>
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#BEFFFFFF"></Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="true"></Condition>
                                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true"></Condition>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#7FFFFFFF"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank You!

Comment: you want to change the foreground color of the labels to black when the listbox is selected?

Comment: Yes that is correct. The problem is that I cannot set a Foreground on a border control so I don't know how to set the style in the template referencing the actual items in the data template...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your triggers are working fine, however I don't see anything that specifies the foreground should be black when an item is selected....

```
  <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Border BorderBrush="#26FFFFFF" BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="5" Name="Border" Margin="0,0,2,3" Padding="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
            <ContentPresenter />
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#7FFFFFFF" />
                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#0FFFFFFF"></Setter>
                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#BEFFFFFF"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="true"></Condition>
                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true"></Condition>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#7FFFFFFF"/>
                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            </MultiTrigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

I do see code that sets the `Foreground` color of a `Label` to white however. This is overwriting any foreground color that you set in your `ListBoxItem` style.

I would suggest adding the default foreground color to your `ListBoxItem` style, and either binding the `Label` foreground color to the `ListBoxItem` foreground color, or using a `TextBlock` instead of a `Label` which will by default inherit the foreground color.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        ...
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And

```
<Label Text="Name" Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=Foreground}"/>
```

Or

```
<TextBlock Text="Name" />
```

Comment: The first two characters are for the Alpha Channel.

Comment: @Lukasz Yes, and WPF doesn't read alpha channels like that. Get rid of them and it will work fine. You can use the `Opacity` property if you want to set transparency

Comment: Removing the Alpha Channel from the color value breaks my style. If on the trigger IsSelected I remove the 7F (127) the selected Item is now completely white. I tried doing <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Opacity" Value="50" /> but it doesn't work. Can you give me an example of how you would fix it? Also if WPF doesn't work like that how come does Blend set all colors with the Alpha Channel? Thanks!

Comment: @Lukasz Oh you're right, I was looking at something else. Anyways, your triggers are fine, but the problem is you have the foreground color set on the Labels inside your ListBoxItem, which is overwriting the `ListBoxItem.Foreground` color. I updated my answer.

Comment: I want to thank you for helping me on this. We are at the same point right now. I have tried to do what you just showed me but you cannot set a Foreground on a Border control. And I tried setting the style as <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" /> but that didn't work as well so I am stuck. I can make the change to TextBlock and have the white inherit from the parent but that still doesn't help me on setting to black on IsSelected...

Comment: @Lukasz That was just a typo... remove the `TargetName="Border"` from your setter.